# Getting the limit to infinity of $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{a^n + b^n +c^n}{3})^{1/n} $?

Tags: real-analysis

Got this one wrong. I see this limit I can see it either being $1$ (because of $1/n$) or $(a + b +c)$ but it isn't.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a^n + b^n +c^n}{3}\right)^{1/n}
$$

Separating it out we get a for sure in the denominator. But infinity to the zero is indeterminate.

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} 3^{-1/n} \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} (a^n+b^n+c^n)^{1/n}
$$

Still confused.

Note: $a,b, c > 0$.

Comment: are a,b, c > 0?

Comment: yes, they are > 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$a < (a^n + b^n + c^n)^{1/n} < a\cdot 3^{1/n}$, so by squeeze theorem the limit is $a$, whereas $a = max\left({a,b,c}\right)$

Comment: why wouldn't a = (a+b+c) instead of the max?

Comment: Because $(b/a)^n \le 1$ and $(c/a)^n \le 1$.

Comment: For possible clarification: Note that the second inequality arises because $a^n+b^n+c^n\leq a^n+a^n+a^n = 3\cdot a^n$ (since we chose $a$ as the largest element).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - That was it!!!